# QGIS formedit signal change value in real time

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I’m developing a QGIS plugin for internal use in the organization where I work. We have a particular case in where we need to be able to detect the event of a change of value in a widget of MapValue type, from the add form of new elements of a layer. It’s similar to the onChange function of common combobox in any frontend language.

Maybe you know which event is it and how can I connect a custom value for getting a value for another field in the same form? Do you have any idea?